# Add description in Swagger for optional parameters in request body

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I would like to add a description in Swagger documentation that some parameters in request body are optional.

Should I use `@ApiParam` annotation for such description ? I tried to use `@ApiModelProperty(notes = "")` but it didnt work.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/users/")
public ResponseEntity<Object> users(@RequestBody PostUserRequest postUserRequest) {}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class PostUserRequest {
    @ApiParam(value = "This is optional parameter")
    private String phone;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look for `@ApiModelProperty` documentation: [doc](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html)
   use `value` instead of `notes` (Currently not in use.)
2. There is an answer for your question about which of this 2 is preferable [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523777/use-apiparam-or-apimodelproperty-in-swagger)

Comment: it doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: try to add `@ApiModel` for class level for `PostUserRequest`

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This parameter is optional", required = false)
```